# Converting ImageSource to Object Throws Binary stream error

Tags: c#, object, xamarin, xamarin.forms, deserialization

I'm trying to convert/cast an image source to an object. I tried to convert to a byte prior to object.

```
ImageSource oImageSelectedByUser = (from ii in mySource where ii.PhotoImgStream != null select ii.PhotoImgStream).FirstOrDefault();
            var oImageAsByte = await ConvertStreamtoByteAsync(oImageSelectedByUser);
            var oImageAsObject =  FromByteArray<object>(oImageAsByte);

   private static async Task<byte[]> ConvertStreamtoByteAsync(ImageSource imageSource)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        try
        {
            if (imageSource is FileImageSource)
            {
                FileImageSource objFileImageSource = (FileImageSource)imageSource;
                string strFileName = objFileImageSource.File;

                var webClient = new WebClient();
                buffer = await webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(new Uri(strFileName));
                return buffer;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            buffer = null;
        }
        return buffer;
    }

    public T FromByteArray<T>(byte[] data)
    {
        if (data == null)
            return default(T);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data))
        {
            object obj = bf.Deserialize(ms);
            return (T)obj;
        }
    }
```

When trying to convert to object, the error I get is:

> Binary stream '0' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. Possible
> causes are invalid stream or object version change between
> serialization and deserialization.

I wanted to ask is there a better way to do this?

Any direction/pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify the code like following

```
 public T FromByteArray<T>(byte[] data)
    {
        if (data == null)
            return default(T);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data))
        {
          
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);  // /rewinded the stream to the begining.
            object obj = bf.Deserialize(ms);
            return (T)obj;
        }
    }
```